# Laravel 1 foriegn key, 2 tables Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have 4 tables and want to tie them together, but I'm getting lost.

```
User
  'id'
  'name' // etc...

Product
  'id'
  'name' // etc...

AnonCart
  'id'
  'unique_id' //tied to session id
  'product_id' // tied to 'id' of Product
  'quantity' //

UserCart
  'id'
  'user_id' //tied to 'id' of User
  'product_id' // tied to 'id' of Product
  'quantity' //
```

I am trying to set up these relationships in Eloquent for my Laravel project

I have the following

**User.php**

```
public function userCarts()
{
    $this->hasMany('\Namespace\UserCart');
}
```

**UserCart.php**

```
public function user()
{
    $this->belongsTo('\Namespace\User');
}
public function product()
{
    $this->belongsTo('\Namespace\Product');
}
```

**AnonUser.php**

```
// doesn't have a user tied to it...
public function product()
{
    $this->belongsTo('\Namespace\Product');
}
```

Finally, I don;t know what to do here. I don't know how to define the Product's relationship to the carts

**Product.php**

```
public function carts()
{
    $this->hasMany('\Namespace\UserCart'); // AnonCart?? 
}
```

How can I solve the problem of having a product linked to 2 different tables but having the same key on both tables?

Is it as simple as having 2 methods ( anonCarts() and userCarts() ??)

Comment: Yes, just have 2 methods. Maybe a `userCarts` method and an `anonCarts` method.

Answer (score 0):

**Product.php**

```
public function userCarts()
{
    $this->hasMany('\Namespace\UserCart');
}

public function anonCarts()
{
    $this->hasMany('\Namespace\AnonCart');
}
```